# Any detectable difference between traffic from HTTP browsing and HTTP downloads?

Tags: load-balancing, http, wide-area-network, traffic-shaping

I am planning to use a multi WAN device for failover and load balancing, with multiple ISPs In my case I would like to maximize performance of HTTP browsing, while diverting on a specific WAN connection HTTP downloading and video streaming.

So I wonder if multi WAN router/devices are capable to detect if a connection is being opened for browsing or downloading, and if this is the case what is the name of this feature/filter/limiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution would probably come in the form of a firewall, used in conjunction with your device (or the device may have pseudo-firewall features). The firewall could differentiate the traffic with the HTTP header 'content-length' and then use it's rules to segregate the traffic above a certain threshold.

However, this doesn't address video streaming, which sends it's data in manageable chunks.

Comment: Is this firewall differentiation a common practice? How would you solve the video streaming configuration?